# AIC and SC tend to select the maximum lag for VECM

Tags: model-selection, aic, vector-autoregression, bic, vector-error-correction-model

I am building a VAR modell in order to discover how oil price shocks and 3 macroeconomic control variables (gdp_growth, Interest rate, exchange rate) influence core and headline inflation in the USA. I use semiannual data from 1986 to 2022. All variables are non-stationary (in case of gdp_g and inflation variables `adf.test` p-value between 0.06 and 0.1 very close to being stationary at levels) but stationary in first differences - so they are all I(1). So I thought the requirements for applying VECM are given. I have a mix of seasonally adjusted and unadjusted variables.
Then I did the model selection and filtered for AIC and SC/BIC information criteria which give me weird results. When I set lag.max to 8,10,12,etc AIC is always at 8,10,12; SC is either at 1 or also at the max (8,10,12,etc). Furthermore, the results for those high lags are not even given - it is written -Inf. (infinity) or NaN.
[image]

I have these results with all variations of the variables and even with other variables that I add and replace. I think I am doing something fundamentally wrong. I think maybe that the discrepancy between the nearly stationary variables at levels and the clearly non-stationary variables at levels has something to do with it.
Can you help me please? What am I doing potentially wrong? Does it mean the model can not be applied and I should consider an ARDL approach? It is my first research I am doing on VECM models. Thanks a lot in advance!

This is my code in R:

```r
----------loading data and analyse via ADF test
HINF <- read_excel("XR_%semiannualHEADLINE.xls")
View(HINF)
ts_HINF <- ts(HINF, start = c(1986,1,1),end = c(2022,1,1), frequency = 2)
ts_HINF
autoplot(ts_HINF)
adf.test(ts_HINF)
-------------Differencing
DHINF <- diff(ts_HINF)
ts_DHINF <- ts(DHINF, start = c(1986,1,1),end = c(2022,1,1), frequency = 2)
ts_DHINF
autoplot(ts_DHINF)
adf.test(ts_DHINF)
----------doing this with all variables
----------then creating the model for Core Inflation  
XR_ALL_CORE <- data.frame(ts_CINF,ts_INTR,ts_RGDP,ts_LEXR,ts_LWTI)
colnames(XR_ALL_CORE) <- c("CINF","INTR","GDP","LEXR","LWTI")
-----------lag selection
var_aic <- VAR(XR_ALL_CORE, type = "const", lag.max = 8, ic = "AIC")
var_aic  -------------
var_aic$p  --------------
lagselect <- VARselect(XR_ALL_CORE,lag.max = 15,type = "const")  -----------
lagselect$criteria  ----------------
lagselect$selection
```

Comment: Hello. Please format your scripts and other relevant things properly to make them legible.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your advice - what exactly you mean? The code only or the text also?

Comment: Richard Hardy already edited your post.